# How to throw an error/warning when annotated method doesn't have a certain parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I've created a custom annotation to log some info when a controller method annotated with it is called. For this, I created a logging aspect class with a method that executes a @before aspect.

The thing is, the aspect method that I wrote relies on that the controller method has a parameter of type HttpServletRequest which has the necessary info that i need to log.

I'd like to know if there is any way to throw a warning when some method with my annotation doesn't have the required parameter.

My custom annotation:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of text.

Comment: @R.G, the answer you linked to is completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: Don't use an aspect, either use a filte which logs always, or if you really want to have it annotation driven, use an `HandlerInterceptor` and implement the `preHandle` method, check for annotation, if available, log what you need (you now always have the request). If you really want the aspect you can also use the `RequestContextHolder` to obtain the request instead of from the method.

Comment: @kriegaex , thanks for pointing out and deleted the same. Apparently I understood the question completely wrong.

Comment: @m.deinum can you explain why is it bad to use an aspect for this purpose? is it performance? thanks

Comment: Because the way you have written it now it is putting a requirement on the implementor of the controller method and thus needs to know the aspect (which kind of beats the purpose of an aspect). AOP on controllers can lead to surpsising issue with annotations not being found by the MVC infrastructure. Doing AOP with controllers is generally better suited in either a `Filter` or an `HandlerInterceptor` depending the need.

Comment: Either way, my answer shows how to print something if the `HttpServletRequest` is **not** found, simply by using `ifPresentOrElse` in your stream operation. That should solve the original problem. I would appreciate a reaction, because I wrote the answer for you, not just for myself.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Arrays.stream(numbers)
      .filter(number -> number % 2 == 0)
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(numbers)
      .filter(number -> number % 2 == 11)
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.err.println("oops"));
  }
}
```

This will log "2" on stdOut and then "oops" on stdErr. Just adapt it to your situation.